# Android is not connecting to database to check the username and password

Tags: php, android, database, xampp

I saw this code in a tutorial video, and in that video the app is working just fine and even showing the "Login successful" toast.

But when I tried to replicate it, it's just not working for me even if I put the correct username and password that is in the database. (I tried on XAMPP with user's LAN IP as well as Wi-Fi IP and also tried to host the PHP script on 000webhost.com but still not working in any of that methods)

My Android code:

```java
package com.example.devarsh.googlemapsbustracker;


import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    private EditText User_name, Pass_word;
    private Button btnlogin;
    private static String URL_LOGIN = 
    "http://192.168.50.127/Android/login.php";


    //vars
    EditText enroll;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnlogin = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        User_name = findViewById(R.id.username);
        Pass_word = findViewById(R.id.password);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Login();
            }
        });


        isServicesOK();
    }

    private void Login(){

        String URL = 
    "imagebustracker.000webhostapp.com/Android/parul/login.php";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                if(response.trim().equals("success")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Selection_Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Unsuccessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Unsuccessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("UserName", User_name.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("PassWord", Pass_word.getText().toString().trim());

                return params;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }


    public void isServicesOK() {
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: checking google services version");

        int available = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if(available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            //everything is fine and user can make map request
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: Google Play Services is working");
        }
        else if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)){
            //there is an error but we can fix it
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: An error is there but we can fix it");
            Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, available, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "We cant make maps request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Android code I just added that if the `response.trim().equals("success")` then it will start a new activity. But it keeps toasting "Login Unsuccessful".

PHP script:

```php
<?php
$conn =
 mysqli_connect("localhost","id7263189_root","dev@1234"
 ,"id7263189_logintb");
    mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$username = $_POST["UserName"];
$password = $_POST["PassWord"];

$query = 'SELECT id FROM logintb WHERE username = "'.$username.'" and 
password = "'.$password.'"';
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('error: ' .mysql_error());

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){

    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "error";
}


?>
```

And currently i'm using XAMPP to connect to myphpadmin. But if i needed i will host this to the 000webhost to check using the real device with the internet.

Comment: The first thing I would recommend you to do is to hardcode the username and password in your PHP code, run the android application, make the call and see if it returns successful result. That will narrow down the problem to see if it's a problem on the Android side or PHP side.

Comment: how can i do that? can you please explain me with an example or change in my code?

Comment: So i have solved this issue by ditching php and moved to Google Firebase but anyways thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, test your PHP script. Therefore, hardcode the username and password variable like this

```
$username = "myUsername"; 
$password = "myPassword";
```

Make sure that myUsername and myPassword is data that actually exists in your database. From there, call the same URL in your web browser and look at the response. Is it a success or error.

Another thing worth noting is reading the response code in your Android app when you are making the call. Response code will clearly determine if it's even communicating with the service or not. But in your case, I would recommend you to print out the Volleyerror. 
Additionally, provide me with the link you used for this tutorial. Sometimes good to have double set of eyes on the code.

As you've mentioned you are encountered with the 'Login Unsuccessful' toast, it means it's hitting the onErrorResponse function. Therefore, change the function to the following: -

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Unsuccessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, error); //or
            System.println("VolleyError Start: " + error + " : End VolleyError");
        }
```

And please share the error. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Here is the link [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlGmC2sx7uc) and yes i tried your method and it worked i used `$username = "test" and $password = "test123"` which is in my database and when i run that php script it works and says success but when i tried in the android studio it says Login unsuccessful again

Comment: you need to share the error with me; therefore, look at the answer again near the end.

Comment: Thanks for the Help I found out the error it's the 000webhosting error but when i tried on the XAMPP localhost server and with emulator it works fine. Special Thanks to Nero for helping me out in this topic

Comment: Your most welcome and glad I could help. If you need any additional assistance, hit me up